# Selenium select with class

Tags: python, class, selenium

I have been learning python now for a while, and just got into selenium lately.

Anyhow..
I want to find text with class 'fs18' on website, and save it into `points_no` --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/z781h.png

Here is my code: `points_no = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs18")`

But that doesnt work at all.. It just gives me this: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x028D77B0>`

Sorry if it's a silly question..

Anyway, i'd appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing correct. For finding text, do this

```
points_no = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs18").text
```

Comment: Btw, the text in fs18 class sometimees takes few seconds to load up, after page has already been loaded. How could i make it wait for it? before saving it into points_no variable?

Comment: Try using Imlicit and explicit waits. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Need to wait 5 minutes before I can accept it. :) I already tried with explicit wait before, will try again.

Comment: This doesnt seem to do anything?
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.class_name, "fs18")))

Comment: Do you mean its just the text that takes time and not the element itself?

Comment: Yes, the text takes 1-2 seconds to load.

Comment: Then use time.sleep(2)

Comment: No problem. Enjoy Python and Selenium :)